# Convergence rate of the secant method

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm having a little trouble doing the part the needs to be proven.  The first part is the definition of approximate error and I just need some help showing that it is equal to the second part of this problem.

If the Secant Method converges to $r$, $f'(r)\neq0$, and $f''(r)\neq0$ then the approximate error relationship $$e_{i+1}\approx\left|\frac{f''(r)}{2f'(r)}\right| e_i e_{i-1}$$ can be shown to hold. Prove that, if in addition, $$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}⁡\frac{e_{i+1}}{e_i^\alpha}$$ exists and is nonzero for some $\alpha>0$, then $\alpha=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and $$e_{i+1}\approx\left|\frac{f''(r)}{2f'(r)}\right|^{\alpha-1} e_i^\alpha.$$

I'm not really sure how I am supposed to start this off.  I get if the limit exists and is nonzero then the limit must be some number $n$, but other than that I'm lost.

Comment: This is hard to read (for old eyes). Try using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

So you found $$e_{i+1}\approx Ce_ie_{i-1},$$ with $C=\left|\frac{f''(r)}{2f'(r)}\right|$. Multiply with $C$, take the logarithm, use $d_i=\ln(Ce_i)$ to get the classical Fibonacci recursion
$$
d_{i+1}\approx d_i+d_{i-1}.
$$
Using the Fibonacci sequence with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$, $F_{i+1}=F_i+F_{i-1}$, the solution for the error sequence can be written as
$$
d_i\approx F_{i-1}d_0+F_id_1\implies e_i\approx\frac1C(Ce_0)^{F_{i-1}}(Ce_1)^{F_i}\le C^{F_{i+1}-1}\max(e_0,e_1)^{F_{i+1}}.
$$
or on the step level
$$
\frac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}\approx \frac{F_{i}d_0+F_{i+1}d_1}{F_{i-1}d_0+F_id_1}
\xrightarrow{i\to\infty}α
\implies d_{i+1}\approxαd_i,~~ e_{i+1}\approx C^{α-1}e_i^α.
$$